# Multiple exposure feature on my Nikon D3300?

Tags: nikon-d3300, multiple-exposure

I have been trying to find a multiple exposure mode on my D3300 but cannot find one, could someone tell me where to find it or if there even is one?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nikon D3300 does [not](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/nikon/d3300) have a built in multiple exposure mode. You can use multiple images from your D3000 and combine them using any post-processing application that offers the feature. The most popular software application that allows you to combine two images is Adobe's *Photoshop*.

Answer (score 2):

Nikon D3300 ... use Image Overlay in the Re-touch menu.  :)

See:  [Image Overlay: Combining Images Together In-Camera](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/image-overlay-combining-images-together-in-camera.html) (nikonusa.com)